# I can't access to the attribute of my class with C++

Tags: c++, function, class, attributes

I have a problem with C++, a can't access to a attribute of my class *Temperatura*.

This is the structure o my project is:
[my project structure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pl2mx5c1r2b0gkc/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202015-04-02%2016%3A52%3A39.png?dl=0)

The file *Temperatura.h* code:

```
#ifndef TEMPERATURA_H_
#define TEMPERATURA_H_

 class Temperatura
{
private:
    float temperatura;

public:
    Temperatura(float);

    //SET's
    void setKelvin(float);
    void setCelsius(float);
    void setFahrenheit(float);

    //GET's
    float getKelvin();
    float getCelsius();
    float getFahrenheit();
};
#endif
```

The file *Temperature.cpp* code:

```
#include "headers/Temperatura.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Temperatura::Temperatura(float t)
{
    temperatura = t;
}

//SET's
void Temperatura::setKelvin(float t)
{
    temperatura = t;
    return;
}

void Temperatura::setCelsius(float t)
{
    temperatura = t + 273.15;
    return;
}

void Temperatura::setFahrenheit(float t)
{
    temperatura = ((t-32)/1.8)+273.15;
    return;
}

//GET's
float getKelvin()
{
    float t = temperatura;
    return t;
}

float getFahrenheit()
{
    return ((9*temperatura)/5)-459.67;
}

float getCelsius()
{
    return temperatura-273.15;
}
```

And the file *Programa1.cpp* code:

```
#include "headers/Temperatura.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Temperatura t(0);
    float grados;

    cout << "Introduzca los grados el setKelvin: ";
    cin >> grados;

    t.setKelvin(grados);
    grados = t.getCelsius();

    cout << "Grados en Celsius: " << grados << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output console is:

```
hunter@Hunter-Elementary:~/Documentos/Distribuidos/Clases/Clase 
2/Proyecto1/Programa1$ g++ *.cpp -o Programa1
Temperatura.cpp: En la función ‘float getKelvin()’:
Temperatura.cpp:33:12: error: ‘temperatura’ no se declaró en este ámbito
Temperatura.cpp: En la función ‘float getFahrenheit()’:
Temperatura.cpp:39:13: error: ‘temperatura’ no se declaró en este ámbito
Temperatura.cpp: En la función ‘float getCelsius()’:
Temperatura.cpp:44:9: error: ‘temperatura’ no se declaró en este ámbito
```

Sorry for my inglish, I speak spanish :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scope your getter functions the same way you did with your setter functions.

```
float Temperatura::getKelvin()
{
    float t = temperatura;
    return t;
}
```

This means that the function is a method of the `Temperatura` class

Comment: Thank you so mouch. I'm a little blind and did not notice. :)